# PHP MAMP - Can't turn on display errors

Tags: php, mamp

I have been trying to enable display_errors for MAMP to figure out an issue that I posted a few days ago. The problem is that after following the path in phpinfo and changing display_errors from Off to On, errors still aren't displaying and phpinfo still says display_errors is Off. I have posted images of the

configuration file path

[image: configuration file path]

display errors being set to on

[image: display errors being set to on]

and phpinfo still showing display errors set to off

[image: phpinfo still showing display errors set to off].

This issue seems to persist when using my laptop as well so I don't think it's an issue with my desktop computer. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Also, did you restart MAMP after you changed php.ini?

Comment: Your second image doesn't show anything turned on. Those `;` prefixed lines are all comments

Comment: @Phil Thank you so much! I had assumed that was what I had to change but as you said that's just a comment. I searched for display_errors and found the one I needed to change and it works perfectly now.